# Get cell value based on cell comment

Tags: vba, excel

I need to get the cell value, if its cell comment matches with my input string.
Is there anyway to do it?

Each cell have date and comment, if the comment match with my search then i need to move this to another cell:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim myComm As Comment
    Dim myInputString As String

    myInputString = "blabla" 'suit it to your needs
    For Each myComm In ActiveSheet.Comments
        If myComm.Text = myInputString Then MsgBox myComm.parent.Value
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: if the user will not add his username to the search string, that won't work. Maybe will need to use `If Instr(myComm.Text, myInputString) > 0 Then`

Comment: @ShaiRado, the user didn't give any clue about its _"input string"_ so I coded straight. should she ever give any feedback, we'll probably know about that. but I'm rather inclined to think we'll never know...

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly for me. But it needs exact match.